# How to have both secure TLS and non-secure communications to redis 7 server?

Tags: ssl, redis, tls1.2

I want to setup redis 7 so that clients can connect to redis server both securely (TLS) and also be able to connect non-securely.

If I can achieve above setup, then
is there a  config option to turn off non-secure and allow only secure connections to redis by either local or remote clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Redis listening both tls and non-tls simultaneously. But you have to use different ports.

In [redis.conf](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/7.0/redis.conf)

```
port 6379
tls-port 16379
```

If you want to disable non-tls. More about this, [here](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/1571907ea02020a829fca63806780c6f3ecf65a0/redis.conf#L190)

```
port 0
tls-port 16379
```